# AVAudioPlayer problem, music not playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile-development

Ребят где может содержатся ошибка, папка с музыкой находится в каталоге @"/Sounds/song.mp3" Все перепробовал. На симуляторе и на девайсе нот воркинг =(
NSError ошибки не выдает.

```
NSError *error;

NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"song" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                         initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
//
//
[player setVolume:1.f];
[player prepareToPlay];

//
[player play];
NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
```

Comment: ну постите свой ответ тогда

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Решено] AVAudioPlayer нужно создавать в проперти, а не локально.

```
 @interface ViewController ()

 @property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer* player;

 @end



 NSError *error;

 NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"song" ofType:@"mp3"];
 self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                     initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
     [self.player setVolume:1.f];
     [self.player prepareToPlay];

     [self.player play];
     NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
```